# \ell in MinionPro

Tags: fonts, symbols

Is it possible to use the `\ell` character from the default font when using MinionPro? If so, how?
The [documentation](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/MinionPro.pdf) actually mentions `\ell` on page 20; the letter is supposed to be taken from MinionPro, I suspect that `\ell` is not part of the fonts I took from Acrobat Reader to install MinionPro.
This example

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{minionpro}
\begin{document}
$\ell$
\end{document}
```

only produces a crossed out box for me.
Maybe with some LaTeX skill it is possible to use something like

```
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ell} {\mathord}{letters}{’140}
```

to take the `\ell` from Computermodern.

Edit: Could someone try to reproduce this problem?

Comment: I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The encoding for `\ell` has changed in newer versions of the MinionPro font. The encoding in the LaTeX package still points at the old glyph code. To fix this, edit the base-MinionPro-ab.enc file. (In Windows, [Search Everything](http://www.voidtools.com) is very helpful for this task.) Simply replace the text `afii61289` with `uni2113` and your script `\ell` characters will magically reappear. This works either before or after the LaTeX font is installed.

Comment: This was a great easy fix. I'm getting the same problem with `\epsilon`. I've noticed `\varepsilon` works fine, so maybe `\epsilon` is just not supposed to be implemented. But if it is, could you give a similar fix?

Answer (score 7):

You can do it with these lines:

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{missing}{OML}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\ell}{\mathord}{missing}{'140}
```

This declares an extra math font called "missing" (as in "missing symbols") which is Computer Modern's symbol font. Then it redefines `\ell` to point to the appropriate character in that font.

However, this apparently uses up one of the ridiculously few slots for math alphabets --- if you use any more, like `\mathcal` and `\mathscr`, then you get the dreaded "Too many math alphabets" error.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have any version of minionpro installed, so I can't test, but in similar circumstances, one thing that has worked for me is to stick it in a savebox *before* loading the new font package, and then redefine the command to use the savebox, i.e., something like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\newsavebox{\oldell}
\savebox{\oldell}{\ensuremath{\ell}}
\usepackage{minionpro}
\renewcommand*{\ell}{\usebox{\oldell}}
\begin{document}
    $\ell$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Good answer, this is the kind of workaround I've been looking for.

Comment: This is a good hack, but it fails when you want to put `\ell` in a subscript.

Comment: Good point. That why hacks are hacks, and not real solutions. I guess a hackish workaround is to use a separate savebox for the subscript `\newsavebox{\suboldell}\savebox{\suboldell}{\ensuremath{_\ell}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Quote from the MinionPro manual:

> If you prefer another math font (such as eulervm) use the option onlytext as explained in Section 3.

Did you try that?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, TechNixe. This changes the mathfont for the entire document, it's not exactly what I'm looking for.