# \openg in MinionPro (from Acrobat 9)

Tags: fonts, symbols

(This is an extension of question [\ell in MinionPro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/3971/6287), but sadly I can't add comments on S.E. yet.)

Similar to the issue of using `\ell` in recent versions of MinionPro, which is solved by replacing `/afii61289` by `/uni2113` in the file `base-MinionPro-ab.enc`, the symbol `\openg` (and probably others, too) is not found anymore due to the changed encoding. What does `/afii10069.ital` have to be replaced by in `base-MinionPro-ab.enc`?

Is there some way of printing a table of all glyphs in a font to find that information?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, by some research I could answer both questions myself:

1. A table of glyphs in a (PFB) font is produced by the command `t1testpage FONT.pfb > output.ps`, producing a PostScript document. By doing so with `MinionPro-It.pfb`, I found the `\openg` symbol as `uni0434.ital` in the output file.
2. Replacing `/afii10069.ital` by `/uni0434.ital` in `base-MinionPro-ab.enc` made \openg work again.

Comment: This fix is included in [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro).

Answer (score 2):

See [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9865/627). The encodings have changed. The MinionPro package has not been officially updated for some time, but there are unofficial updated encodings [here](https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/minionpro-devel/attachments/20090814/4e956ea2/attachment.zip).

Answer (score 0):

You can print out all glyphs in the following way, say you have `MinionPro-Regular.otf` file, then first step is, (If you already have the `pfb` file, which is quite possible since you are using the `MinionPro` package, then this step can be ommited)

```
cfftot1 MinionPro-Regular.otf > MinionPro-Regular.pfb
```

Next you can create the `ps` file which has all the glyphs with glyph names.

```
t1testpage MinionPro-Regular.pfb > MinionPro-Regular.ps
```

Then you can view the `ps` depend on your OS, for example on Mac OS X, open it directly and Preview will convert it to `PDF` file. Or you can,

```
ps2pdf MinionPro-Regular.ps
```

to create the `PDF` file.