# What I need to use extra symbols in MinionPro?

Tags: symbols, minionpro

I've just installed MinionPro fonts for LaTeX, as it is written in the HowTo of the `minionpro` package. My font's version is "`Version 2.030;PS 2.000;hotconv 1.0.51;makeotf.lib2.0.1867`. Than, I tried to test the fonts, and use extra symbols by `\PiSymbol` command, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\Pisymbol{MinionPro-Extra}{110}
\end{document}
```

Compiling this with `pdflatex`, it gives the following message:

```
 pdfTeX warning: pdflatex (file
 /usr/share/texmf/fonts/type1/adobe/MinionPro/Min
 ionPro-Regular.pfb): glyph `orn.011'
 undefined
```

And in the PDF output, an ugly box appears instead the expected symbol.

Please give any hints, where to look for the reason of this error, what is missing for it to work. I've googled a lot, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Thanks for correcting my code box, i haven't known how to create it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works for me. I have "Version 1.021; PS 001.001; Core 1.0.35;makeotf.lib1.5.4492". It seems that adobe has changed the glyph name from "orn.011" to "bullet.011" so it seems you will need to edit the encoding files (and then post the fixed version to the mailing list at minionpro-devel@lists.berlios.de)

Comment: Super!!! It works! So, now i'm editing the encoding file, and i will post to the mailing list. Thanks!

Comment: Now, i renamed most of the symbols; but, a few specimens still missing: 'blackdiamond', 'blackleftpointingtriangle', 'blackrightpointingtriangle', 'blacksquare', 'fisheye', 'orn.024', 'orn.028', 'orn.030', 'whiteleftpointingtriangle', 'whiterightpointingtriangle'. How can i get information, what are the new names of them?

Comment: You can use, for example, fontforge.

Comment: Maybe you could also try the encoding files here (I have not tested them): https://lists.berlios.de/pipermail/minionpro-devel/attachments/20090814/4e956ea2/attachment.zip

Comment: These are all perfect. So, it seems that the developers already have the correct files. Thanks!