# Using Minion Pro's Ornaments in pdflatex

Tags: fonts, font-encodings, minionpro, ornamental-fonts

I am having some trouble with getting Minion Pro's ornaments (with `pifont`) to work in `pdflatex`. When I compile the PDF all I see is a box with an "X" in it.

Although I have taken a look at at several posts on tex.SX, [the only one that I have found to be relevant to my issue](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9865/what-i-need-to-use-extra-symbols-in-minionpro) does not explicitly say what to do to fix the problem.

**Here is my MWE.**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{MinionPro}
\usepackage{pifont}
\begin{document}
\Pisymbol{MinionPro-Extra}{110}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Thanks for always being so willing to help others out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never mind, I grepped for `orn` in `~/Library/texmf`, and found the corresponding file: `~/Library/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ad.enc` Then I ran `$ sed -i .bak 's/orn/bullet/g' ~/Library/texmf/fonts/enc/dvips/MinionPro/base-MinionPro-ad.enc`, which completely solved the problem.