# Install MyriadPro on MacOS/Texlive 2013

Tags: fonts, pdftex

I tried to install MyriadPro using FontPro ([FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro)). Everytime I try to compile a latex document with pdflatex I get the following error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+597/600 --dpi 597 MyriadPro-Bold-tosf-t1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for MyriadPro-Bold-tosf-t1--base.
mktexpk: perhaps MyriadPro-Bold-tosf-t1--base is missing from the map file.
```

I had no problems installing MinioPro the same way.

Any ideas?

I used the following commmands:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro.git
$ cd FontPro
$ mkdir otf
$ cp /Applications/Adobe\ Reader.app/Contents/Resources/Resource/Font/*.otf otf
$ ./scripts/makeall MyriadPro
```

There were a lot of message of the following form:
     tlf-ly1,warning: kpathsea: configuration file texmf.cnf not found in these directories: /opt/local/etc/texmf.

But those messages also appeard when I successfully installed MinionPro

```
$ sudo ./scripts/install /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/
$ sudo updmap-sys --enable Map=MyriadPro.map
```

Resulting in the following output (same with MinionPro):

```
updmap: resetting $HOME value (was /Users/chris) to root's actual home (/var/root).
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap is using the following updmap.cfg file for writing changes:
  /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap: top config file /usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg has not been read. at /usr/texbin/updmap line 1334.
```

EDIT: I just found out that MinionPro is not installed properly. The compiled PDFs look "pixelated".

Comment: Please tell us which commands you used. Just saying you followed that isn't very specific as it covers several different options even for a single OS. For example, did you use `updmap` or `updmap-sys`? Did you use `sudo` or run as root or run as yourself? Did you get any errors? Which `texmf` tree did you install into? Etc.

Comment: The installation script appears to be looking for your installation of TeX in `/opt` whereas it is almost certainly in `/usr/local/texlive`. I'm not sure why the `updmap.cfg` is not read. Does that file exist on your system? It may not be an error if not if you've not installed any additional fonts before.

Comment: Try `./scripts/makeall --help` to see if there's an option allowing you to specify the correct location for the TeX installation.

Comment: Why are you using pdfTeX with (presumably) OpenType fonts in 2014 when you can use XeTeX and LuaTeX which make font installation much easier?

Comment: @MartinSchröder: Because pdflatex offers full microtype support.

Comment: @Sugor: As does LuaTeX.

Comment: @MartinSchröder: As http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/microtype/microtype.pdf suggest in table 1 LuaTex does not support kerning and spacing.

Comment: @Sugor follow this underrated answer http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47726/36131 to install MinionPro, so once that problem is taken care of (which it will) then go back to FontPro and install MyriadPro.

Comment: @MartinSchröder You often post that. It's obvious that people like to flock to the "easier" (i.e. safe and sound) process unless there has been a major shift in the public eye (in this case, pdftex users) that a new process (i.e. LuaTeX) [improved](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/75118/why-does-it-take-lualatex-so-long-to-load-fonts-and-can-i-speed-it-up).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a bug, or an error in the install directions, as I had the same result.  Only, I managed to get MinionPro installed using FontPro, and it works amazing.  Tried more or less the same thing with MyriadPro, and get exactly the same error about MyriadPro-Bold... is missing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!