# Error while building a GitHub template

Tags: minionpro, macos

I was trying to build this project https://github.com/Ritterbecks/Hausarbeit, when I got this error:

```
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-grad/pst-grad.sty:1104: LaTeX Error: File `MinionPro.sty' not found. [\usepackage]
```

I tried to comment out the line 1102 of `packages.tex` (where is asked for the `MinionPro` package), but then I get huge list of `Undefined control sequence` error that I don't think it's worth to post.

Any ideas? Someone can succeed in the compilation?

The environment I am using is macOS 10.12.6, Sublime Text 3 with LatexTools and the building engine is the default `pdflatex`.

Comment: BTW: There are mistakes in that template, e.g., adding the last page of the `bibliography` into the table of contents instead of the first one. I cannot recommend usage of this template.

Comment: @Schweinebacke how to install Minion Pro through `getnonfreefonts`? In the documentation it's not mentioned and I didn't find googling. Anyway, disabling the usage of this font should not generate all the others errors, am I wrong? It would be a waste to not be able to use this template because it's really awesome!

Comment: Oh, sorry, you are right. I'm wong.

Comment: `MinionPro.sty` is part of [`minionpro` CTAN package](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/minionpro/README) or [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro/). Note, you need commercial fonts files! See [MinionPro on Mac OS X](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2641/minionpro-on-mac-os-x).

Comment: If your question is not about the MinionPro problem you should edit your question and ask for one of the other problems. However, once again: The template is faulty. I would not use it.

Comment: @Schweinebacke Thanks! I edited the title, I hope it fits fine now.

Comment: No. If you have a question about an error be specific and show us at least the error message! Currently you are showing an error about missing `MinionPro.sty`. So the question is still about missing `MinionPro.sty`. And if you've changed the template, show us the change! And don't expect us to fix all the mistakes of the template. Bugs should be reported to the author.

Comment: Disabling that file may well produce additional errors if the document uses control sequences defined or redefined by that package or by packages that package loads. For example, I believe that at least some copies of the MinionPro package load `fontaxes`. If those macros are never used, that's one thing; otherwise, of course you'll get errors.

Comment: This isn't a template. It is a document. It is not designed to be used as a template and should not be used as one. I don't know if it claims to be a template. I'm simply saying what it is. The term 'template' is not well-defined, it is true, but if anything is to distinguish 'templates' from sample documents, this is not going to fall on the template side of that distinction.